# How do I make a for loop of a loop in general?

Tags: rust

Could you please help?

```
fn main() {
    let mut count = 0;
    for count == 5 {
        count++
        print!("{}", count);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted is not valid Rust, and "I found many posts" is not a description of what you want code to do. What do you want your code to do?

Comment: To count to 5. Also yes that's why I'm asking for help why is everyone so condescending

Answer (score 2):

I think you're crossing your wires on for and while loops. A for loop iterates through a list or range of items.  A while loop has a end condition that terminates the loop.  Examples below:

```
// for loop
// https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/for.html
fn main() {
    // `count` will take the values: 0 , 1, 2, ..., 5 in each iteration
    for count in 0..=5 {
       print!("{}", count);
    }
}

// while loop
// https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/while.html
fn main() {
    // A counter variable    
    let mut count= 0;

    // Loop while `count` is less than 5
    while count < 5 {
      count +=1;
      print!("{}", count);
    }
}
```